# Which distribution has higher VaR?

Tags: statistics, value-at-risk, statistical-finance

Let say I have 2 distributions with cdf $F_1$ and $F_2$. And I know that $F_1 \leq F_2$. With this information I know that $F_1$ has bigger lower tail than $F_2$ but I don't think this right away doesn't mean that $F_1$ has bigger VaR. How can I conclude which distribution have higher VaR?

Comment: I’d say that if $F_1(x)\leq F_2(x) \forall x$ then $F_1$ should have the higher VaR, i.e. the worse quantile. If the two cdfs intersect, you’d need to know whether they do so before or after the target probability.

Comment: Also, maybe [stochastic dominance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance) could be helpful here?

Comment: @Kermittfrog I also think that it is $F_1$ but that's but I'm hopping for a mathematical proof. I'll check stochastic dominance